# interop pass structure from c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++, interop

c# code :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Message
{
    public uint MsgId;
    public uint DLC;
    public uint Handle;
    public uint Interval;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public byte[] Data;
};
```

I have to send this structure to a function in the c++ native .dll as follows :

```
    [DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public static extern int AFT_iSetRTSECANWrapper(IntPtr Data);
```

I am preparing the buffer like this  :

```
        Message frame = new Message();
        frame.MsgId = (uint)MsgId;
        frame.DLC = (uint)DLC;
        frame.Interval = (uint)Interval;

        frame.Data = new byte[64];

        for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
        {
            frame.Data[i] = 11;
        }

        //Transmit message 
        int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(frame);
        IntPtr frameBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(frame, frameBuffer, false);

         AFT_iSetRTSECANWrapper(frameBuffer);
```

in c++ i have the following structure:

```
    typedef  struct { 
unsigned int MsgId;
unsigned int DLC;
unsigned int Handle;
unsigned int Interval;
    unsigned char Data[64]; 
 } Message;
```

and the function to be called is this :

```
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int AFT_iSetRTSECANWrapper(Message *data)
```

After this i simply try to access the fields in the Message with data->DLC but i got nothing. I can't figure out what's the problem here.

Comment: sizeof(char) == sizeof(byte), so it should be "unsigned char Data[8]. "

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  What does "i got nothing" mean?  Use the debugger to look at "data", you should at least see the 0x0b byte values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the data is not allocated in the same contiguous section as the rest of the structure so it is not transferred across.  Try

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Message
{
    public uint MsgId;
    public uint DLC;
    public uint Handle;
    public uint Interval;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public byte[] Data = new byte[64];
};
```

For the C++ bit instead of transferring to an intptr, transfer directly

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
public static extern int AFT_iSetRTSECANWrapper([in,out] Message Data);
```

Send your message as

```
Message frame = new Message();
frame.MsgId = (uint)MsgId;
frame.DLC = (uint)DLC;
frame.Interval = (uint)Interval;
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
{
    frame.Data[i] = 11;
}

//Transmit message 
AFT_iSetRTSECANWrapper(frame);
```